# Any Tricks to Use in wkhtmltopdf and pdftk to Reduce File Size?

Tags: macos, pdf, wkhtmltopdf, pdftk

I'm using `wkhtmltopdf` on OS X, and while it has been generally working as intended, the size of the files it generates is larger than I had hoped for. My goal is to essentially save a screenshot of the text content webpage as a pdf, and I don't really care about the images, hyperlinks, and other features on the page. I've been using the tool in conjunction with `pdftk` to save the first page of a website as a pdf, and below is an example of my code for the desired webpage (http://espn.go.com/mens-college-basketball/boxscore?gameId=400589702):

```
/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf http://espn.go.com/mens-college-basketball/boxscore?gameId=400589702 --zoom 0.65 /Users/dwm8/Desktop/test.pdf
/usr/local/bin/pdftk /Users/dwm8/Desktop/test.pdf cat 1 output /Users/dwm8/Desktop/test2.pdf dont_ask
```

The size of the final file test2.pdf is 487 KB, which is larger than I would prefer. Are there any tricks I can use in `wkhtmltopdf` or `pdftk` to reduce the file size? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you don't care about hyperlinks or images, the obvious thing to do is suppress them using `--disable-external-links` and `--no-images`. If you are really only interested in the text, which is black and white, you may as well only generate a greyscale PDF too:

```
/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf --disable-external-links --no-images --zoom 0.65 --grayscale http://espn.go.com/mens-college-basketball/boxscore?gameId=400589702 result.pdf
```

which gets the file size down from 500kB to 70kB on my system - a fairly useful 86% space saving!

Comment: Wow, this works perfectly, thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

You could pass in `--lowquality true` as this is used to shrink the generated pdfs size.

More information on options can be found here http://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt

Comment: `--lowquality` is to be used without `true`.